# Angular2 - routing error - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, typescript2.0

Trying to create a simple routing in Angular2:

ERROR in 
C:/projects/gamefication/src/app/app.routing.ts (8,7):

```
Type '({ path: string; redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; } | 
{ path: string; component: string; })[]' 
is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.

Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; } | 

{ path: string; component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
Type '{ path: string; component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
  Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'
```

app.routing.ts as below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo:'/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'explorer', component:'ExplorerQuizComponent' },
{ path:'login', component: 'LoginComponent'}];

@NgModule({imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ], exports: [ RouterModule ]})`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove ' , Please Try:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo:'/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'explorer', component:ExplorerQuizComponent },
{ path:'login', component: LoginComponent}];
```